# Pandas: Not Json serializable despite decoding

Tags: python, json, utf-8, serializable

```
df['attr1'].unique()
```

gives:

```
array([b'C84', b'C3', b'C63', b'C60', b'C62', b'C58', b'C31', b'C55'])
```

so I decode with:

```
df['attr1'] = df['attr1'].str.decode('utf8')
df['attr1'].unique()
```

gives:

```
array(['C84', 'C3', 'C63', 'C60', 'C62', 'C58', 'C31', 'C55'])
```

The attribute values are being used in a chord graph using the Bokeh library but I don't think this is the problem. I applied the same procedure as before to another column, 'attr2' and executed the following using Bokeh:

```
chord = Chord(df, source='attr1', target="attr2", value="weights")
show(chord)
```

The specific json related error relates to:

```
json.dumps(obj, cls=BokehJSONEncoder, allow_nan=False, indent=indent, 
separators=separators, sort_keys=True, **kwargs)
```

Which tries to serialise to JSON and gives:

```
TypeError: b'C55' is not JSON serializable.
```

Is Bokeh looking at a previous dataframe? In which case, perhaps I am not decoding and replacing the original dataframe?

Comment: Can you show us more of your code? Like, your call to `json.dump` or whatever?